# ¿Cómo ordenar dos listas al mismo tiempo en Python?

Tags: python, lista, ordenar

Tengo dos listas en Python, una se corresponde a los nombres de los clientes, y la otra al monto total de facturación en el período.

La posición de cada cliente en la lista corresponde a su total en la misma posición en la lista de montos, por ej:

```
topnombre2 = [Roque Tulio, Javier Pintos, Carlos Alvarez]
topmonto2 = [4600, 3400, 19890]
```

Roque Tulio facturó un total de $4600, Javier Pintos un total de $3400, etc.

Lo que necesito es ordenar la lista de montos de mayor a menor, haciendo que la posición de cada nombre se corresponda con la de su monto. Esto para crear un listado de los clientes que más compraron.

Intenté con este ciclo pero no funciona:

```
    for i in range(0, len(topmonto2)):
        for j in range(1, len(topmonto2)):
            if topmonto2[j] > topmonto2[i]:
                x = topmonto2[i]
                y = topnombre2[i]
                topmonto2[i] = topmonto2[j]
                topnombre2[i] = topnombre2[j]
                topmonto2[j] = x
                topnombre2 = y
```

Larga este error:

```
File "", line 97, in listaclientes
    topnombre2[i] = topnombre2[j]
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

No entiendo por qué sería un str

Si alguien me puede dar una mano le agradecería bastante. Gracias!

Comment: Hola. Bienvenido a stackoverflow en español. Debes colocar c/u de los strings que tienes en la lista de nombres entre comillas. Sean de una palabra o de multiples separadas por espacios.

Comment: Hola @JoelAssad,  para este caso me parece que es mucho mejor utilizar un diccionario, veo que sos nuevo acá, sabes usarlos? Si no lo sabes, te recomiendo que veas algún tutorial en YouTube, o alguna web, etc., ya que sería mucho más fácil para vos matchear los nombres de las personas con las del monto de facturación. Saludos.

Answer (score 5):

Puedes hacer el uso de dos funciones:

- [sort](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort) : Ordenar la lista.
- [zip](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_zip.asp) : Crea un iterador y puedes iterar más de un conjunto a la vez.

Por ejemplo:

```
nombres = ["Roque Tulio", "Javier Pintos", "Carlos Alvarez"]
montos = [4600, 3400, 19890]

for monto, nombre in zip(montos, nombres):
    print(monto, nombre)
```

Resultado:

```
4600 Roque Tulio
3400 Javier Pintos
19890 Carlos Alvarez
```

De esta manera iteramos las dos listas y al imprimir el resultado vemos que los imprime en el orden en el que se encontraban las listas.

Ahora usando sorted podemos ordenar ese resultado.

```
for monto, nombre in sorted(zip(montos, nombres)):
    print(monto, nombre)
```

Resultado:

```
3400 Javier Pintos
4600 Roque Tulio
19890 Carlos Alvarez
```

Vemos que el resultado lo ordena de menor a mayor a partir de la lista de montos.

Ahora podemos usar un parámetro de la función `sort` llamado `reverse` -lo puedes revisar en la documentación- para ordenar de forma inversa y obtenerlos de mayor a menor como deseas:

```
for monto, nombre in sorted(zip(montos, nombres), reverse = True):
    print(monto, nombre)
```

Resultado:

```
19890 Carlos Alvarez
4600 Roque Tulio
3400 Javier Pintos
```

Answer (score 1):

Joel, me parece que una solución más simple y sencilla es crear un diccionario que contenga el nombre de los clientes junto con los montos de facturación de los mismos, en vez de tener dos listas distintas, ya que con un diccionario es más fácil leer cuánto facturó cada cliente.

Además, es más fácil a la hora de agregar nuevos clientes.

```
clientes = {}

clientes["Roque Tulio"] = 4600
clientes["Javier Pintos"] = 3400
clientes["Carlos Alvarez"] = 19890
clientes["Pirulo"] = 5098611


for i in sorted(clientes, key=lambda k: clientes[k], reverse=True):
    print(i, clientes[i])
```

La función `sorted` se utiliza de manera predeterminada para ordenar el diccionario utilizando la `key` del diccionario, en esta caso, los nombres de los clientes, de manera alfabética. Es por eso que además, utilizamos la clave `key=lambda k: clientes[k]`. Esta te permite, utilizando una función anónima lambda, decirle a `sorted` que quieres ordenar el diccionario teniendo en cuenta el `value` del diccionario, en esta caso, los valores del monto de facturación de cada cliente. Y el `reverse=True` se utiliza para ordenarlos de forma descendente (de mayor a menor), ya que la forma predeterminada es de ascendente.

Espero que te sirva. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Apuesto a que no lo has depurado línea por línea, si no ya te hubieras dado cuenta que el error no se da la primera vez que se ejecuta el código dentro del `if`, sino la segunda vez que se ejecuta el código.

Esto es debido a qué, la primera vez que se ejecuta, asignas una cadena a la variable que antes contenía un arreglo de cadenas, el código relevante dentro del `if` es este:

```
                y = topnombre2[i]
                #...
                topnombre2[i] = topnombre2[j]
                #...
                topnombre2 = y
```

¿Ves claramente el origen del error?, al final, asignas la cadena almacenada en `y` a la variable `topnombre2`.

Por eso, la segunda vez que se ejecuta, `topnombre2` ya no tiene un arreglo de cadenas, sino una sola cadena. La línea `y = topnombre2[i]` almacena en `y` el `i`esimo caracter de la cadena, y todo revienta en `topnombre2[i] = topnombre2[j]`, pues no puedes asignar un valor a un caracter `i` de una cadena, que es lo que dice el mensaje de error:

> 'str' object does not support item assignment

Mi traducción libre sería:

> objeto 'str' no soporta asignación de posiciones

Me parece obvio que lo que pretendías hacer (que no ha salido por un error que cualquiera puede cometer), es **intercambiar los valores de las posiciones del arreglo**, algo como:

```
                y = topnombre2[i]
                topnombre2[i] = topnombre2[j]
                topnombre2[j] = y
```

El código funcional completo quedaría entonces:

```
    for i in range(0, len(topmonto2)):
        for j in range(1, len(topmonto2)):
            if topmonto2[j] > topmonto2[i]:
                x = topmonto2[i]
                y = topnombre2[i]
                topmonto2[i] = topmonto2[j]
                topnombre2[i] = topnombre2[j]
                topmonto2[j] = x
                topnombre2[j] = y
```